# Отправка SMS сообщений используя GSM модуль

Tags: linux, sms, at

Есть GSM модуль, с помощью которого необходимо отправить SMS.
Я смог отправить SMS с помощью AT command через minicom, сейчас стоит задача отправить SMS сразу из терминала Linux, для того чтобы в ставить данные команды в программу на Golang
находил как это сделать с помощью `echo`, но ничего не получилось:

```
echo -e 'AT+CMGS="89169478466"\n' > /dev/ttyAMA0 
echo -e 'qwerty\n' > /dev/ttyAMA0
echo -e '^Z' > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

GSM модуль подключен к  `/dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: А если попробовать в одну строку?
`echo -e 'AT+CMGS="89169478466"\nqwerty^Z' > /dev/ttyAMA0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo apt-get install gammu
sudo gammu-config

[image: Начальная конфигурация]
[image: Итоговая конфигурация]

```
echo "Dragon Ball super is Awsome!" |sudo gammu --sendsms TEXT 8**********
```

https://techexpert.tips/ubuntu/send-sms-from-ubuntu-linux-command-line/